# $xml->addAttribute ignoring/escaping two points ":"

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to update my actual sitemap.xml to match google news sitemap requisites.
I just added the string:

```
--> $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:news', 'https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9');

  $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset/>');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns:news', 'https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9');
```

and as the result it get me the following:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" news="https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
```

it cut "**xmlns:**"
it cut just anything before "**:**"
i don't know how to solve it.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: When you want to use a prefix you also must provide the namespace as the third parameter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the XML content you want to build.